# How to use Zend_Loader_Autoloader

Tags: zend-framework

I think this is a reasonably easy question however I just don't get autoloading in Zend framework.

Basically, I have the standard Zend project layout with application/models, application/controllers, application/views directories.  I have also added an application/forms directory, and the classes that it contains will be named Application_Form_*

How do I register the new directory with the autoloader?

Thanks...

Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register the new directory with the autoloader. If you create a form it should look something like like this:-

application/forms/Myform.php

```
class Application_Form_Myform extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        //Put your code here
    }
}
```

You can then instantiate your form like this (in your controller for example):-

```
$myform = new Application_Form_Myform();
```

Zend Framework will then autoload the class for you.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-form.html

There is an explanation of [Autoloading in Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.autoloading.html) in the manual.

An extract from that:-

> Zend Framework has borrowed an idea from » PEAR, whereby class names have a 1:1 relationship with the filesystem. Simply put, the underscore character ("_") is replaced by a directory separator in order to resolve the path to the file, and then the suffix ".php" is added. For example, the class "Foo_Bar_Baz" would correspond to "Foo/Bar/Baz.php" on the filesystem. The assumption is also that the classes may be resolved via PHP's include_path setting, which allows both include() and require() to find the filename via a relative path lookup on the include_path.

Which basically means that folders don't all need to be registered in the autoloader. It can quite happily find files in folders anywhere under the application or library/Zend folders so long as you follow the naming convention and proper casing.

The default folders under application/ that end with an 's' are special cases specifically dealt with in `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader::initDefaultResourceTypes()` and should not be confused with the main autoloading mechanism.

Comment: OK, so application/forms is automatically registered, in the same what that application/controllers is.  What other directories are automatically registered, I wonder?

Comment: @KimPrince: See the source code of the class `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` for a complete list of the default resource autoloader mappings.

Comment: @vascowhite: But my directory is application/forms (Note the plural, forms...) and my class name is Application_Form_*, so there is no 1:1 mapping.  See David Weinraub's comment above....

Comment: @DavidWeinraub Those mappings are in `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`. Actually, I didn't know about `mappers` and `dbTable`, so thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @vascowhite: D'oh! My fingers are faster than my brain. ;-( Thanks for the correction. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$resourceLoader`:

```
$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
    'acl' => array(
        'path'      => 'acls/',
        'namespace' => 'Acl',
    ),
    'form' => array(
        'path'      => 'forms/',
        'namespace' => 'Form',
    ),
    'model' => array(
        'path'      => 'models/',
        'namespace' => 'Model',
    ),
));
```

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html